# input.click() do not work from IconMenu

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I'm trying to implement smart image uploader with https://github.com/callemall/material-ui.
It has placeholder `div` element and `IconMenu` on top.
I have the following code:

```
onPlaceHolderClick = () => {
  this.input.click();
};

// ...
```

```html
<IconMenu
  iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
  anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}
  targetOrigin={{ horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' }}
  onItemTouchTap={this.onMenuTap}
>
  <MenuItem primaryText="Load more" onTouchTap={this.onPlaceHolderClick} />
  <MenuItem primaryText="Delete all" onTouchTap={this.onDeleteAllClick} />
</IconMenu>

// ...

<div onClick={this.onPlaceHolderClick}>Load more</div>

// ...

<input
  onChange={this._handleFileSelect}
  ref={input => this.input = input}
  style={{ display: 'none' }}
  type="file"
  multiple={multi}
/>
```

`onPlaceHolderClick` is called every time, but in case of `IconMenu` nothing happens. The console is empty.

Comment: try to use `.focus()`

Comment: I've tried to use it, no luck. Also I've tried to make it always visible.

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected action you want by clicking "Load More"?

You do have access to the **clickEvent** in `onPlaceHolderClick`

```
onPlaceHolderClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
};
```

But maybe you are wanting to start an http request in the "Load More" element?

Comment: I just want standard dialog to show up.

I've tried to add new `IconButton` next to `IconMenu` and it works just fine (I thought maybe the problem is in `IconButton` implementation).
Also I've tried to pass `<label htmlFor="input-id"> ...` to `primaryText` of `MenuItem`, but with no result.
`console.log(event.target.value);` prints `undefined`, but event itself is not empty.